# Are non-alphanumeric characters acceptable in a Maven path?

Tags: maven, naming-conventions

What is the convention for group and artifact names in [Maven coordinates](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Maven_Coordinates)? Should I stick with alphanumeric characters?

I know that dots (`.`) indicate subgroups in a group name, and dashes (`-`) are word separators.

Do tools choke on non-alphanumeric characters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally you can use any characters as long as they could be used in file names on OS you're running Maven at. The groupId, artifactId and version can became name of file or folder on file system, so name should be legal.

For example, with standard local Maven repository layout, an artifact with group id org.apache.maven.plugins, and artifactId maven-compiler-plugin and version 2.3.2 will became a file with path like:

```
org\apache\maven\plugins\maven-compiler-plugin\2.3.2\maven-compiler-plugin-2.3.2.jar
```